# Python 3: Traceback : TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, traceback

I'm new in python 3 and I don't understand why I get a Type Error (this is a guess a number game for numbers between 0-100):

```
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
low = 0 
high = 100
check = False
while True :
    guess = (low + high)/2
    print("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.\n")
    print("Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.\n" )
    print("Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.\n")
    ans = input("")  
    if ans == "h" :
        low = ans
    elif ans == "l" :
       high = ans
    elif ans =="c" :
        print( "Game over. Your secret number was:{}".format(guess))
        break
    else :
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
```

here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

Thanks in advance.I'd really appreciate your help I'm stuck in this

Comment: You need to put full traceback. But from your code: when user input anything, except `c`, it will raise an error, because you assign input value(`str` object) to `low` or `high` variable and then trying to do `int` operation. first time `+` and then `/2`

Comment: Yes, you change "low" or "high" to a string in the first two parts of the conditional.  Then when the while loop starts over again it tries to use them as integers to calculate "guess" again.

Comment: This isn't much of a game; the player isn't guessing a number so much as choosing a number based on the sequence of `h`s and `l`s they enter.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `low = ans` you set low to be a string value, the string value "h"

Then on the second time you pass through the loop, you try to calculate
`(low + high`)/2`  You can't calculate  ("h" + 100)/2 because you cant add the string to the integer. This is a "type error"

For each line explain to a friend (or a soft toy) what each line does and why you are certain each line is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. You should probably print the guess so that the user knows whether it is too high or too low
2. `low==ans` doesn't make any sense. `ans` will either be "h", "l", or "c", assuming the user follows the rules. `low` and `high` need to be numbers in order to generate the `guess`  appropriately

Also your logic was incorrect. The below code works.

```
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
low = 0
high = 100
check = False
while True:
    guess = (low + high)/2
    print("My guess is: %i" % guess)
    ans = input("Enter 'h' if guess it too high, 'l' if too low, or 'c' if correct: ")
    print(ans)
    if ans == "h":
        high = guess
    elif ans == "l":
        low = guess
    elif ans == "c":
        print("Game over. Your secret number was:{}".format(guess))
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
```